# npm Err! code Error. Trying to install robotjs. New to

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

[image: npm Err! code 1]

What's wrong and what do I need to do?

New to coding, much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: *"could not find visual studio installation to use"* you have Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, you need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the Desktop Development with C++ workload, or at least install the Visual Studio Build Tools.

[image: screenshot of relevant part of error message]

Comment: you don't actually need the whole Visual Studio - Visual Studio Build Tools is enough

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for letting me know, I've edited my post to include the info :)

Answer (score 0):

2024 update - I've encountered a similar issue, however robotjs does not work with latest node and npm. my solution was:

1. Uninstall everything (node, npm, python)
2. Install node 12.16.1 (and make sure to select "automatically install the necessary tools")
3. at this point npm will fail saying that it needs newer version of node (navigate to C:\Users<your user>\AppData\Roaming and delete npm and npm-cache)
4. open shell or cmd and type "npm install -g npm@6.13.4"
5. install python version 2.7.0 and inside your terminal type: npm config set python "C:\Python27"
6. open vscode and type: npm i robotjs